# How to write conditional probability in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy

I am not sure if that's a place to ask here (my type question)?

I am working to code in python but I am struggling to interpreter that to Python.

My question is : I have `Pr(A | B)` in the case of dependent which is equal to

`Pr ( A ∩ B ) / Pr(B)`. I know how to do it by program, but I mean can I do that by python. On my idea I just multiply `Pr ( A ) * Pr (B)` then I / Pr(B). Which I think is not correct is there anyway to write that the conditional probability in python program, or what did is correct?

Comment: Your proposed implementation of conditional probability assumes independence, and is in fact just *Pr(A)*. This follows from both your formula and intuition.

Comment: yes, P (A ∩ B) is not equal to P(A) * P(B) if event A and B are dependent

Answer (score 2):

if you know values of P(A ∩ B) and P(B) , you can compute P(A | B) using

```
pB = 0.3
pAB=0.4

pAifB = pAB / pB
print(pAifB)
```